# pyodbc [DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()) Error

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

Hi i'm using python3 with pyodbc package

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=tread;DATABASE=sa;UID=sa;PWD=sa')
```

it will give following error.
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection. (14) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()). (14)')

what would we the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check all the parameters which you pass inside connection.